# Yii2 form field modify value with regex

Tags: php, html, yii2

i have an edit form (WYSIWYG editor as the text input) in yii2 with default value a table (the table is coming from my database) with multiple style tags like this

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:694px">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td style="height:15.75pt; width:128pt">Dimension</td>
        <td style="width:11pt">:</td>
        <td style="width:381pt">31 mm x 8 mm</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="height:15.75pt">Band width&nbsp;</td>
        <td>:</td>
        <td>18 mm</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="height:15.75pt">Case&nbsp;</td>
        <td>:</td>
        <td>Stainless steel | Ceramic bezel</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="height:15.75pt">Finishing</td>
        <td>:</td>
        <td>Stainless steel</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="height:15.75pt">Glass</td>
        <td>:</td>
        <td>Scratch resistant mineral glass</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="height:15.75pt">Strap</td>
        <td>:</td>
        <td>Leather strap</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="height:15.75pt">Buckle</td>
        <td>:</td>
        <td>Stainless steel</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="height:15.75pt">Movement</td>
        <td>:</td>
        <td>Quartz 3 hand movement</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="height:15.75pt">Function</td>
        <td>:</td>
        <td>Hour | Minute | Second</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="height:15.75pt">Water resistant</td>
        <td>:</td>
        <td>3 ATM</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

i want to remove every single style tags in that table before rendering the table in my WYSIWYG editor as the default value, how can i achieve this? this is my code

```
<div class="col-sm-10">
    <?= $form->field($productDetail, 'spesification')->textarea(array("rows" => 10, "cols" => 80))->label(false) ?>
</div>
```

i know i have to use `preg_replace` to remove all the style tags like the code below, but i'm not sure how to implement this in the form field. so can anyone tell me how to use this code below on my form field or is there any other solution? thank you

```
$productDetail->spesification = preg_replace('/ style=("|\')(.*?)("|\')/', '', $_POST['ProductDetail']['spesification']);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of the wall, the regexp you try to use would leave `style=` part of string, that is bad. You should use `preg_replace('/(\sstyle=["\'].*["\'])/gU', '', $input)` instead.

Second, you're trying to replace some POST data, not the generated HTML code. You should use `$form->field()` returned value as `$input` in function above, like this:

```
<div class="col-sm-10">
    <?php
      $field = $form
        ->field($productDetail, 'spesification')
        ->textarea(array("rows" => 10, "cols" => 80))
        ->label(false);
      $clearField = preg_replace('/(\sstyle=["\'].*["\'])/gU', '', $field);

      echo $clearField; 
    ?>
</div>
```